# Amcharts - HTML tags in some Labels

Tags: javascript, amcharts

I use the following chart: http://www.amcharts.com/demos/stacked-bar-chart-with-negative-values/#theme-none

Now I want to add html tags to some labels. (not to all.)

Example: (Here I wanna use strong)

```
"dataProvider": [{
    "age": "<strong>85+</strong>",
    "male": -0.1,
    "female": 0.3
  }, {
    "age": "80-54",
    "male": -0.2,
    "female": 0.3
  }, ..... ],
```

Result: [image]

Comment: I suggest you to find css class for this label 85+ and give it font-weight: bold; I think its name (amcharts-axis-label) so you can write this css in your page .amcharts-axis-label{font-weight: bold;} 
I hope this help you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The category axis labels in amCharts are SVG nodes and therefore do not support HTML tags.

What you can do is to target specific labels using CSS.

To do that, you will first need to enable application of CSS classess to chart elements, by setting [`"addClassNames": true`](http://docs.amcharts.com/3/javascriptcharts/AmSerialChart#addClassNames).

Then target labels using CSS. Each category axis label has class `"amcharts-axis-label"` set. You can target the first one using CSS's `nth-child` selector:

```
.amcharts-category-axis .amcharts-axis-label:nth-child(1) tspan {
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

(I also used `.amcharts-category-axis` selector so that value axis labels are not targeted by this)

Here's the whole working chart with the above working:

```js
var chart = AmCharts.makeChart("chartdiv", {
  "type": "serial",
  "rotate": true,
  "addClassNames": true,
  "marginBottom": 50,
  "dataProvider": [{
    "age": "85+",
    "male": -0.1,
    "female": 0.3
  }, {
    "age": "80-54",
    "male": -0.2,
    "female": 0.3
  }, {
    "age": "75-79",
    "male": -0.3,
    "female": 0.6
  }, {
    "age": "70-74",
    "male": -0.5,
    "female": 0.8
  }, {
    "age": "65-69",
    "male": -0.8,
    "female": 1.0
  }, {
    "age": "60-64",
    "male": -1.1,
    "female": 1.3
  }, {
    "age": "55-59",
    "male": -1.7,
    "female": 1.9
  }, {
    "age": "50-54",
    "male": -2.2,
    "female": 2.5
  }, {
    "age": "45-49",
    "male": -2.8,
    "female": 3.0
  }, {
    "age": "40-44",
    "male": -3.4,
    "female": 3.6
  }, {
    "age": "35-39",
    "male": -4.2,
    "female": 4.1
  }, {
    "age": "30-34",
    "male": -5.2,
    "female": 4.8
  }, {
    "age": "25-29",
    "male": -5.6,
    "female": 5.1
  }, {
    "age": "20-24",
    "male": -5.1,
    "female": 5.1
  }, {
    "age": "15-19",
    "male": -3.8,
    "female": 3.8
  }, {
    "age": "10-14",
    "male": -3.2,
    "female": 3.4
  }, {
    "age": "5-9",
    "male": -4.4,
    "female": 4.1
  }, {
    "age": "0-4",
    "male": -5.0,
    "female": 4.8
  }],
  "startDuration": 1,
  "graphs": [{
    "fillAlphas": 0.8,
    "lineAlpha": 0.2,
    "type": "column",
    "valueField": "male",
    "title": "Male",
    "labelText": "[[value]]",
    "clustered": false,
    "labelFunction": function(item) {
      return Math.abs(item.values.value);
    },
    "balloonFunction": function(item) {
      return item.category + ": " + Math.abs(item.values.value) + "%";
    }
  }, {
    "fillAlphas": 0.8,
    "lineAlpha": 0.2,
    "type": "column",
    "valueField": "female",
    "title": "Female",
    "labelText": "[[value]]",
    "clustered": false,
    "labelFunction": function(item) {
      return Math.abs(item.values.value);
    },
    "balloonFunction": function(item) {
      return item.category + ": " + Math.abs(item.values.value) + "%";
    }
  }],
  "categoryField": "age",
  "categoryAxis": {
    "gridPosition": "start",
    "gridAlpha": 0.2,
    "axisAlpha": 0
  },
  "valueAxes": [{
    "gridAlpha": 0,
    "ignoreAxisWidth": true,
    "labelFunction": function(value) {
      return Math.abs(value) + '%';
    },
    "guides": [{
      "value": 0,
      "lineAlpha": 0.2
    }]
  }],
  "balloon": {
    "fixedPosition": true
  },
  "chartCursor": {
    "valueBalloonsEnabled": false,
    "cursorAlpha": 0.05,
    "fullWidth": true
  },
  "allLabels": [{
    "text": "Male",
    "x": "28%",
    "y": "97%",
    "bold": true,
    "align": "middle"
  }, {
    "text": "Female",
    "x": "75%",
    "y": "97%",
    "bold": true,
    "align": "middle"
  }]
});
```

```css
#chartdiv {
  width: 100%;
  height: 500px;
}

.amcharts-category-axis .amcharts-axis-label:nth-child(1) tspan {
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<script src="http://www.amcharts.com/lib/3/amcharts.js"></script>
<script src="http://www.amcharts.com/lib/3/serial.js"></script>
<div id="chartdiv"></div>
```